# Exclude node_modules from tslint in an Angular project

Tags: angularjs, tslint

I'm trying to configure codelyzer so that I can run tslint over all the source files in my project, but obviously excluding node_modules.

I configured my script in package.json like this

```
"lint": "tslint --type-check --project tsconfig.json"
```

So if I understand tslint should use tsconfig.json to check which files should lint.
When I run `npm run lint` I get an error in my app.component.ts, which is fine, but I also get a few errors from files within node_modules, something like this

```
Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ɵmakeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function
    at simplify (/Users/david/Documents/work/my-angular-seed/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21818:58)
    at simplifyCall (/Users/david/Documents/work/my-angular-seed/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21624:28)
    at simplify (/Users/david/Documents/work/my-angular-seed/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21806:52)
    at simplifyInContext (/Users/david/Documents/work/my-angular-seed/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21831:28)
    at simplify (/Users/david/Documents/work/my-angular-seed/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21667:40)
    at simplifyInContext (/Users/david/Documents/work/my-angular-seed/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21831:28)
    at simplify (/Users/david/Documents/work/my-angular-seed/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21789:52)
    at simplify (/Users/david/Documents/work/my-angular-seed/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21649:60)
    at simplifyInContext (/Users/david/Documents/work/my-angular-seed/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21831:28)
    at recordedSimplifyInContext (/Users/david/Documents/work/my-angular-seed/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21844:28) 'node_modules/@angular/core/typings/core.d.ts'
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "strictNullChecks": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useWebpackText": true,
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useCache": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

and my tslint.json is the standard version as in the [npm site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/codelyzer)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

EDIT

I got a response from the [github repo for codelyzer](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/issues/268).
It seems the problem is in the beta version, so I updated my package.json to version 2.0.1 and problem solved.

Only issue now is that I get an error when I execute tslint via package.json script I get an error, but if I run it in the command line then it works fine.

`tslint --project tsconfig.json`

```
11 silly lifecycle my-angular-seed@1.0.0~lint: Args: [ '-c', 'tslint --project tsconfig.json' ]
12 silly lifecycle my-angular-seed@1.0.0~lint: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
13 info lifecycle my-angular-seed@1.0.0~lint: Failed to exec lint script
14 verbose stack Error: my-angular-seed@1.0.0 lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json`
14 verbose stack Exit status 2
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:192:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:192:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:890:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```